# Sort custom post archives by a meta value from a different custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, hooks, meta-query

To make a long story short, I have a custom post type called `artworks` with these meta fields:

```
title
catalog_no
artist_key
```

I have a second custom post type called `artists` with these meta fields:

```
artist_key
artist_firstname
artist_lastname
```

Obviously, the `artist_key` field is used to relate the artist to their works.  It contains alphanumeric strings such as "anvcih5-8745".

On category archives pages such as https://example.com/artworks/sculpture, I want to sort the results by artist_lastname.

In SQL I believe I would achieve this by doing an INNER JOIN, but I'm struggling to understand how to achieve the same thing in Wordpress.

I've figured out that I can add a [posts_join](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join) filter that will allow me to join to another table.  I have written the following hook and confirmed that it's firing on the correct page:

```
function archives_artwork_join($join)
{
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        $qo = get_queried_object();
        if ($qo->name == 'sculpture') {
          // modify $join here
        }

        return $join;
    }
}
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'archives_artwork_join' );
```

But, I don't know how to write the JOIN statement.  And I don't even know whether I am on the right track with this approach.

Am I on the right track here, or is there a better approach I could take to sort the artworks category archives by artist last name?

Comment: Have you tried using the `pre_get_posts` hook and set `meta_key` to `artist_key` and `orderby` to `meta_value` ?

Comment: artist_key just contains a string like NABLJKGUIH3TH87.  It takes three joins to link it to the artist's last name, which is stored under a different custom post type.  I eventually did solve this a different way, but the query was too slow to be used.  So, I ended up implementing a custom template that first loads all posts in the category into an array, then loads all artists whose IDs were mentioned, relates the two based on artist key, sorts the first array, and then takes out a slice that represent the current page of results.  It's much faster, even though it has to load more records.

Comment: Okay and you should post an answer. :)